# Returning a subset of a navigation propertie's object

Tags: entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-6

I have a one to many relationship as outlined below.  In some parts of the business layer there are queries of the Item table and in others the Client table (as well as its Items).   LazyLoading and ProxyCreation are both false, reference loop handling is set to ignore.

```
public class Client {
 public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }   
 public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Item {
  public virtual Client TheClient {get;set;}
  public string ItemProp {get;set;}
  // another 10 properties or so
}

 myitems = dbContextScopeX.Items.Include(x => x.Client).ToList();
```

The view has a list of items with the need to show the Client's Name (in my example).  I am looking for item.Client.Name ultimate, however when `myitems` gets queries/serialized it contains:

```
myitems.Client.Items
```

If I set the attribute [JsonIgnore] on the Client's Item property it never comes through the graph which I need it to in other places.  Is there a way to get myItems.Client.Name without having to get `myitems.Client.Items` in the query or without having to create an anonymous projection for the Item array?

Comment: Have you tried projecting to an anonymous type which excludes the Items collection and serializing that type?

Comment: I simplified the example.  In my project Items has other navigation properties that go down a couple levels.   Also, I know I can use the ClientID which comes back on the Item class and look it up, but I wanted to see if there was an easier way to get the name.

Comment: Another thing you might try is simply nulling the Items collection on the Client (or set it to an empty list) before serializing. Just make sure you don't try to do anything else with that DbContext before you dispose it as the entity relationship will be all screwy. This sounds to me like a rather hacky and unadvisable way to accomplish your goal, but it might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project the Item properties you want (be they simple or complex type) along with just the Client name into an anonymous type and serialize that.

```
myitems = dbContextScopeX.Items.Include(x => x.Client)
    .Select(i=>new {
        ItemProp = i.ItemProp,
        ItemCollection = i.ItemCollection,
        ...
        ClientName = i.Client.Name
    }).ToList();
```

Only caveat is you have to do some manual work if you want to deserialize this back into entities.

Comment: Thanks for noting the caveat, I was trying to avoid having to manually create anonymous object although your answer definitely works.  Let's see if I can get any other answers.